# What's the rule for writing sentences with parallel clauses?

Tags: grammar, terminology, ellipses, parallelism, compound-sentences

I've sometimes seen very nicely written sentences that have 2 clauses: the first is a full sentence, while the second, which is supposed to have a similar structure, was shorten into a special structure. Something like this:

"A1 use B1 to do C1, and A2 B2 C2."

For example:

- "My brother goes to school by bus, and I by bicycle."
- "I'm going to the supermarket to buy a can of milk, and you the hardware store a hammer."

I'm not sure if these are even grammatically correct or not, but just to show what I mean.

Does this kind of sentence structure have a name? What are the rules?

Please forgive my English as I'm a non-native Engineering-based speaker.

EDITED: I've managed to find one sentence: "The winds will blow their own freshness into you and the storms their energy, [...]". Here, "and the storms their energy" was very nicely written. I'd like to know more about how to write such a sentence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sentences in your examples are examples of [Zeugma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma), and reading that Wikipedia article will be a good start toward learning to write your own. This may inspire you to study [rhetoric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetoric) in general, including other forms of [ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_%28linguistics%29) and [parallelism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_%28rhetoric%29). A full course on the subject is well beyond the scope of this site, but I hope these pointers are of use.

Comment: Thanks, Nicholas. I've been wondering about this for a long time. :-)

Answer (score 0):

While the sentences can be regarded as zeugmas, I find it more enlightening to consider them as examples of [ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_%28linguistics%29).